# How to play a sound on a checkbox in html css

Tags: html, jquery, css, audio, html5-audio

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="img/toggle.mp3" ></audio>

<div class="buttonpos">
    <input class="toggle" onchange="myfunction" type="checkbox" id="switch">
    <label onchange="document.getElementById('myaudio').play();" for="switch" class="switchLabel">
        <span class="switchLabelBg"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Why does this not work? I am trying to make a sound play when i click on my checkbox!

Answer (score 0):

After playing around, the `document.getElementById('myaudio').play();` should actually be in the other `input` tag in the HTML, so if you changed the HTML to that is should work:

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="img/toggle.mp3" ></audio>

<div class="buttonpos">
    <input class="toggle" onchange="document.getElementById('myaudio').play();" type="checkbox" id="switch">
    <label for="switch" class="switchLabel">
    <span class="switchLabelBg"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```